# What are Access _be and _bp files and how do they link together?

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm trying to fix and add some functionality to an Access Database that a group I work with uses. They have a `FileName.accdb` file which holds the queries and forms. The data seems to be stored in one of two other database files `FileName_be.accdb` and/or `FileName_bp.accdb` both stored in a 'Back End' Folder beside the `FileName.accdb` file.

I was hoping someone might be able to explain how all this might link together, there is no documentation on how it was organized.

The other thing that seems odd to me is that 3 files are similar in size:

FileName.accdb  = 11MB

FileName_be.accdb = 10.1MB

FileName_bp.accdb file = 7.5MB

The _bp and _be files both only have the database tables, but the _bp file seems to be more up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is split into Frontend and Backend. See e.g. 

[Microsoft Access Split Database Architecture](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/DatabaseSplitter/).

FileName.accdb should have **linked tables**, queries, forms and code.

FileName_be.accdb sounds like a backend, having only tables.

FileName_bp.accdb - if it's newer, maybe "bp" is "backend production", but that's just a guess.

Open FileName.accdb and open a linked table in design view. In the property sheet, the **Description** will tell you where the table is linked from. The tooltip in the navigation bar will do so too.

Alternatively, you can use **External Data -> Linked Table Manager** to re-map these file locations.